# How to add Cloudwatch output to runShellScript document on an EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, ssm

I have a python script on an EC2 which needs to run daily without anyone manually kicking it off. My current setup uses a scheduled Lambda function to send an SSM Document as a command to the EC2. The SSM Document includes a short "runShellScript" command to run the python script. (see below for the SSM document and abbreviated lambda function). This process works fine.

The issue is that I need the logs to stream to CloudWatch. I'm aware that CloudWatch can retrieve log files which are sitting on the EC2; However I want Cloudwatch to capture the logs directly from stdout (standard-out), rather than taking the log files.

When I manually run the SSM Document via the "Run Command" section of the AWS UI, it sends it to Cloudwatch beautifully since I directly configure the CloudWatch as part of the Run Command kickoff. However I don't see anywhere to configure Cloudwatch as part of the Document.

**How can I adjust my SSM Document (or any piece of this process) to stream the logs to CloudWatch?**

I'm open to changing schemaVersions in the document if that would help. I already looked through the SSM Parameter documentation for this but could not find an answer there.

Here is the relevant section of the Lambda function:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # Execute the script
    ssm = boto3.client('ssm', region_name=region)
    ssm_response = ssm.send_command(InstanceIds=instances, DocumentName='CustomRunScript', Comment='Starting init script from lambda prod')
    print('SSM response is: ', ssm_response)
```

Here is my SSM Document:

```
{
  "schemaVersion": "1.2",
  "description": "Custom Run Script",
  "parameters": {},
  "runtimeConfig": {
    "aws:runShellScript": {
      "properties": [
        {
          "id": "0.aws:runShellScript",
          "runCommand": [
            "/usr/bin/python3 /home/app/init.py"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for `CloudWatchOutputConfig`.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Execute the script
    ssm = boto3.client('ssm', region_name=region)
    ssm_response = ssm.send_command(
        InstanceIds=instances,
        DocumentName='CustomRunScript',
        Comment='Starting init script from lambda prod',
        CloudWatchOutputConfig={
            'CloudWatchLogGroupName': 'some-group-name',
            'CloudWatchOutputEnabled': True,
        },
    )
    print('SSM response is: ', ssm_response)
```

Answer (score 0):

> When you send a command by using Run Command, you can specify where you want to send the command output. By default, Systems Manager returns only the first 2,500 characters of the command output. If you want to view the full details of the command output, you can specify an Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) bucket. Or you can specify Amazon CloudWatch Logs. If you specify CloudWatch Logs, Run Command periodically sends all command output and error logs to CloudWatch Logs. You can monitor output logs in near real-time, search for specific phrases, values, or patterns, and create alarms based on the search.

Note you will need to provide proper IAM permissions for the Lambda  to access the log group.  Those permissions are listed in the reference below.

See [Configuring Amazon CloudWatch Logs for Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-rc-setting-up-cwlogs.html)